# Spring Boot enum JSON serializer

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, enums

Below is the object that I want to convert to JSON;

```java
public class TestDto{
    private ResponseType responseType;
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

The `ResponseType` below is an enum;

```java
public enum ResponseType{ 
    TEST1("test message 1"), TEST2("test message 2"), TEST3("test message 3");
    private String message;
}
```

Below is the JSON which I want to create:

```json
{"code":"TEST1", "message":"test message 1", "id":1, "name":"name"}
```

and code in the JSON response points the name of the enum and the message in the JSON response points the message field of the enum.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the JSON support in the Jackson library. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to add derived getters/setters to `TestDto`, and suppress JSON serialization of the `responseType` field.

```java
class TestDto {
    private ResponseType responseType;
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore // Suppress JSON serialization
    public ResponseType getResponseType() {
        return this.responseType;
    }
    public void setResponseType(ResponseType responseType) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    public String getCode() { // Derived getter for "code" property
        return this.responseType.name();
    }
    public void setCode(String code) { // Derived setter for "code" property
        this.responseType = (code == null ? null : ResponseType.valueOf(code));
    }

    public String getMessage() { // Derived getter for "message" property
        return this.responseType.getMessage();
    }
    @Deprecated // Shouldn't be called by Java code, since it's a dummy stub method
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setMessage(String message) { // Derived setter for "message" property
        // Ignore value
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

*Two-way test*

```java
TestDto testDto = new TestDto();
testDto.setResponseType(ResponseType.TEST1);
testDto.setId(1L);
testDto.setName("name");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(testDto);
System.out.println(json);

TestDto testDto2 = mapper.readValue(json, TestDto.class);
System.out.println(testDto2.getResponseType());
System.out.println(testDto2.getId());
System.out.println(testDto2.getName());
```

*Output*

```
{"id":1,"name":"name","message":"test message 1","code":"TEST1"}
TEST1
1
name
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my previous answer as it wasn't correct. You can use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` to indicate that the enum should be serialized like an object (based on the getters).

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
    public enum ResponseType{
       TEST1("test message 1"), TEST2("test message 2"), TEST3("test message 3");
       private String message;

       ResponseType(String message) {
          this.message = message;
       }

       public String getMessage() {
          return message;
       }

       public String getCode() {
          return this.toString();
      }
   }
```

After that, you must also use `@JsonUnwrapped` on the Enum field to avoid having it's fields serialized as an object.

```
    public static class TestDto {
       @JsonUnwrapped private ResponseType responseType;
       private Long id;
       private String name;
    }
```

Running the following code

```
    TestDto testDto = new TestDto(ResponseType.TEST1, 1234356L, "First Response");
    result = mapper.writeValueAsString(testDto);
    System.out.println(result);
```

I get the result `{"message":"test message 1","code":"TEST1","id":1234356,"name":"First Response"}`

Comment: That does not output 2 properties for the 1 enum: `response` field -> `"code"` and `"message"`.

Comment: I misunderstood the request, will update the answer to match the problem.

Comment: @Slimu with this annotations I got json {"message":"test message 1", "id":1234356,"name":"First Response"} without name of enum value

Comment: Did you add the explicit getter in the enum?